# Choosing which database to use when starting the application

Tags: asp.net, database, web-config

I'm developing a web application which will be use by 3 departments, and each of them will have its own database, because if a problem occurs (like a bad manipulation by a humain...  which occured last week...) and I have to restore the database for one department, I don't want to impact the 2 others.

What I want to do is when my application start for Dept-A I want the application to use Database-A, and so on for Dept-B and Dept-C.

I know it is possible in the Page_Init code to set the datasource to the right database to use in the code for the current page, but in my ASPX pages all my SqlDatasource has a ConnectionString pointing to the web.config, that's what is blocking me.  It would be easy if upon start I can set dynamically the database name to use in the webconfig connection string, but sadly it seems not possible.

For now my solution will be to deploy my app to 3 different website, each one will have the same code but their webconfig will contains the right database for them.

This will work but I just want to be sure that there is no easier solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't a multi-tenant application a solution to your problem?

Comment: @JordyDeweer: a multitenat app is a solution to this problem

Comment: To the OP: you don't want to "set dynamically upon start" or rather, you want if by "start" you mean start of each request. Read what options you have assuming you change your app a little bit to make it multitenat. This is definitely possible, we have apps for thousand tenants.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, first time I heard about multi-tenant app.  In fact my app is still under developement but well advanced and already use by one department.  At first I was using a single database with and ID_DEP in many tables to separate the data.  But like I said I wish to separate the database for each department.  I search for an example on how to build a multi-tenant app but no success...   I work in ASP NET with VS 2017 and SQL server, where can I find what changes I need to do for this?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-tenant app. That way, you can set a different connection string per tenant.

It requires little modifications, for a simple app. You could also use a framework like ABP.